# WPF knowledge required before moving to MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I'm developping windows applications with WPF since 1 year .. I want to get started with MVVM pattern.

- What are excatly all things I should get Hands-on to start MVVM pattern comfortably ?
  (Any Interesting Links are Welcome)

Comment: This question belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com not stack overflow.com

Comment: I think It's not as frequently visited as stack overflow, but i've posted it anyway

Comment: Just because SO has more traffic doesn't mean you should post it on SO.

Comment: Actually I think this question doesn't belong *anywhere*... there are dozens of MVVM tutorials on the web, Google will find them for you in no time.

Comment: One year is way too long before getting started with MVVM. It's at the heart of WPF imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's 2 instructional video links I usually give out that helped me get started:

http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650

http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=315275

In the end you'll most likely migrate to one of the well built MVVM frameworks that do a lot of the dirty work for you like this one that I currently use:

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/

It is important to first learn how to hand roll your own MVVM frameworks for your apps, then you can move on to one of the pre-built frameworks to save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/Josh-Smith

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.